# How do I know what my stackexchange url is to merge accounts?

Tags: discussion

I am submitting a query to have multiple accounts merged but it asks for the stackexchange url. I have no idea how to find what these are (definitely not tech savy... at all).

The username and wordpress url is not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it can be the "network profile" link in your profile https://stackexchange.com/users/13111538/shelley